# Trying to invoke GitHub RestApi call from Powershell to create a Git Tree and getting "Problems parsing JSON"

Tags: rest, api, powershell, github

I am making a call as follows and getting 'Problems parsing JSON' error.

```
    $pair = "XXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
    $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
    $Body="{
  `"base_tree`": `"2267699d5ea2a632c625693ceef5f7b77b2cda74`",
  `"tree`": [
    {
      `"path`": `"synthetics/MyAccount-MakeAPayment.js`",
      `"mode`": `"100644`",
      `"type`": `"blob`",
      `"content`" : `"require('new-relic-synthetics-manager');
         //----- Add synthetic code below this line
        //////////MORE CODE HERE TO CHECKIN///////////`"
    }
  ]
}"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://api.github.com/repos/MYORGANISATION/Test/git/trees" -Body $Body -Headers @{Authorization = $basicAuthValue}
```

I was trying to execute the api mentioned in the github API documentation https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree and create a tree prior to committing those changes.

My requirement is to modify multiple files and commit the changes in single go so I will not able to rely on Content API mention at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file.

When I try to execute the code snippet mentioned earlier I am getting the error.

> "message": "Problems parsing JSON"

I know that in the Body's content property I am providing scripts and which contains newline characters, double quotes, single quotes etc What we need to do for checking-in similar kind of scripts?

I have noticed that even if we are providing one newline character in the content it is failing with the same error. Even the Rest Api is not taking any base 64 encoded string. On providing base64 encoded string Api call is executing without any errors but we are getting tree created with encoded string. Which is not desirable.

Any suggestions or workaround in the API or powershell will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you write out your JSON block using a `here-string` and get rid of all the backticks to escape the quotation marks.
That way, it is much easier to spot if it is valid json or not.

```
$Body= @"
{
    "base_tree": "2267699d5ea2a632c625693ceef5f7b77b2cda74",
    "tree": [{
        "path": "synthetics/MyAccount-MakeAPayment.js",
        "mode": "100644",
        "type": "blob",
        "content": "require('new-relic-synthetics-manager')"
    }]
}
"@
```

Use an online JSON validator like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to check if it indeed is valid json.

JSON does not use comment lines; it is all data.